# How to make a build command in Geany IDE to compile and execute Objective-C programs?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, execute-command, geany, objective-c

I am a big fan of Geany IDE and Ubuntu. I am learning Objective-C programming language. I have Objective-C Environment in Ubuntu 16.04 and I compile Objective-C programs using terminal. But I want to make a build command in Geany for that purpose. But Geany recognises Objective-C programs which have .m file extension as Matlab/Octave commands. So suggest me a method to compile & execute Objective-C programs directly from Geany by making a build command in Geany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geany should already have a build configuration for Objective-C, provided by the `filetypes.objectivec` file (part of the `geany-common` package):

```
[build_settings]
# %f will be replaced by the complete filename
# %e will be replaced by the filename without extension
# (use only one of it at one time)
compiler=gcc -Wall -c "%f"
linker=gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lobjc
run_cmd="./%e"
```

The tricky part is making geany actually choose that, instead of the one for Matlab (since both filetypes are associated with the `.m` extension in the `filetype_extensions.conf` file). Currently, the only way I know to do that is to manually select the filetype from the <kbd>Document</kbd> menu

```
Document --> Set Filetype --> Programming Languages --> Objective-C
```

After that, you should be able to build your file from the <kbd>Build</kbd> menu as normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! But I am still getting a problem. I am able to run my file easily after following the above steps. But when I compile my file, I get this message:                                                                                                                      gcc -Wall -c "HelloWorld.m" (in directory: /home/gkv/Desktop/objectiveC)
HelloWorld.m:1:33: fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Compilation failed.
(HelloWorld.m is the name of the Objective-C file I made)

Comment: I am able to execute Objective - C programs correctly but I get error during compiling which I have stated in the above comment. Please help me get rid of this compiling error.

Comment: @GautamVashisht I don't know anything about Objective-C, but my guess is you either don't have the [Foundation Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_Kit) in your environment (or need to specify its include path, if you do).

Comment: I have Foundation Kit in my environment due to GNUStep. I think it is not accesible outside the GNUStep's workspace or IDE as I am using Geany. I will find its solution later on. But thanks a lot for your help. You have really helped me improve my workflow.

Comment: It may be as simple as adding the GNUStep include path to your build options e.g. `-I /usr/include/GNUstep` - anyway good luck

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing and it worked. Now I am not getting any compiling errors. Thanks a lot !